# Android query and store contact duplicates number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am currently trying to query all contacts and store into database. However, I realize this problem, if my contact has multiple numbers, it returns me same contact name and the other multiple numbers. But if my contact has email, the query will duplicate the same name and same number. May I know how do I go about resolving this? I would only want to store the name and number once. And I would want nothing to do with the email.

I managed to get only the mobile number by defining that I only want TYPE_MOBILE. However, I realized that if my contact has Google +, the query duplicates the same name and same number. Can anyone guide me along this line? Thanks!

Here is the code I am using:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    int phoneType = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
    if (phoneType == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
    {
          mobile = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
          mobile = mobile.replaceAll("\\s", "");
          id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          long idL = DbHelper.createContact(name, "", mobile, "", id);
          if (idL > 0) {
                mRowId = idL;
          }
    }   
    phones.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't save numbers to your db. it is not correct way to do this on Android.
when you need to find name of an number query contacts and search. because user can change sth about contact and so you will have old data on your db.

Comment: Because I am trying to do a contact list that is similar to Viber. I am trying to display my app's icon beside the contact if the contact has the same app. Otherwise, do you have any other suggestions? :)

Comment: so, save only numbers id from contact list. try to work your app with id numbers. and if you want not to duplicate numbers fecth them to an arraylist and while fetching them, check if arraylist contains that number. after that save numbers' ids to your db

Comment: Hi, now I am able to check for the phone type and then save the mobile number. But I realized that the number will still be duplicated if the contact has Google +. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I will update my code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
```

in your while loop

```
if(!list.contains(mobile)){
    list.add(mobile);
}
```

after filling the list you can save them.

BUT, I think same about the saveing numbers to your db. instead of saving them save their ids'.